# bootstrap glypicon not appearing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

The bootstrap icon piggy-bank does not get displayed.

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-piggy-bank"></span>
```

Plnkr here: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/zjOLWS1M6NT9PJYSwWfj

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using an older version - if you use 3.3.2+, the piggy bank will appear. Here's the modification you need:

```
<link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.2" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.*" data-semver="3.3.2" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.2" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

[Here's your upgraded example](http://plnkr.co/edit/OFKufFjasjJsSVDOhHyn?p=preview).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think piggy bank glyphicon is part of Bootstrap 3.1.1.

Change CSS to 3.3.2 and it should work

Also, I'd recommend this app in general - Offers a great suite of icon fonts

https://icomoon.io/app

Comment: Thanks for the additional icons